# finding keyword in an xml file with binary format

Tags: c++, xml, binaryfiles

I've got an xml file in a binary format. I want to extract some keyword contained in some line in this file with a c++ code. Let's say I want to find the following keyword `<GK-VECTORS>` and I know that the keyword exists in the file. Here is my c++ code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

int main(){
  int size(8);
  ifstream gfile("gkvectors.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
  string keyword = "<GK-VECTORS>";
  string line;
  while( gfile.good() ){
    getline(gfile,line);
    bool found = line.find(keyword);
    if( found != string::npos ){
      cout << line << '\n';
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output that I got from executing this files is not (human)readable:

```
�
```

Here is how the inside of the (unformatted) xml file looks like:

```
^D^@^@^@^E^Z^@^@^D^@^@^@^^^@^@^@\200^Z^@^@
<?iotk version="1.2.0"?>
^^^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^E^]^@^@^D^@^@^@!^@^@^@\200^]^@^@
<?iotk file_version="1.0"?>
!^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^E^U^@^@^D^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@\200^U^@^@
<?iotk binary="T"?>
^Y^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^E^X^@^@^D^@^@^@^\^@^@^@\200^X^@^@
<?iotk qe_syntax="F"?>
^\^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^A^N^@^@^D^@^@^@^R^@^@^@\200^N^@^@
<GK-VECTORS>
^R^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^A;^@^@^D^@^@^@?^@^@^@\200;^@^@
  <NUMBER_OF_GK-VECTORS type="integer" size="1" kind="4">
?^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\255^C^@^@^H^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^B^[^@^@^D^@^@^@^_^@^@^@\200^[^@^@
  </NUMBER_OF_GK-VECTORS>
^_^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^A?^@^@^D^@^@^@C^@^@^@\200?^@^@
  <MAX_NUMBER_OF_GK-VECTORS type="integer" size="1" kind="4">
C^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\326^C^@^@^H^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^B^_^@^@^D^@^@^@#^@^@^@\200^_^@^@
  </MAX_NUMBER_OF_GK-VECTORS>
#^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^A1^@^@^D^@^@^@5^@^@^@\2001^@^@
  <GAMMA_ONLY type="logical" size="1" kind="4">
5^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^B^Q^@^@^D^@^@^@^U^@^@^@\200^Q^@^@
  </GAMMA_ONLY>
^U^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^AC^@^@^D^@^@^@G^@^@^@\200C^@^@
  <K-POINT_COORDS type="real" size="3" kind="8" UNITS="2 pi / a">
G^@^@^@^\^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^B^U^@^@^D^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@\200^U^@^@
  </K-POINT_COORDS>
^Y^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^A.^@^@^D^@^@^@2^@^@^@\200.^@^@
  <INDEX type="integer" size="941" kind="4">
```

Could someone help me to fix this issue, so that I can get a readable output?

Comment: What exactly does "XML in binary format" look like? XML is, by definition, an ASCII format. Perhaps you could show a simple example of what your file might look like.

Comment: @lurker How do I add that file here? The xml file is actually produced by some fortran code with xml format but activating binary =  .true. in the "write(unit, binary=.true.)"

Comment: @rnels12 You have a binary file format and read that using `getline()`??

Comment: You don't have to add the exact file. Just give an example of what it looks like or at least describe it in more detail. If you're not sure what it looks like, then that's a starting point to solving your problem.

Comment: Because, according to its original fortran code, the file is written per line. Is there any better suggestion other than using `getline()`?

Comment: Is the XML file viewable in a text editor?  or do you need an editor that can view the file in hex (a.k.a. hex editor)?

Comment: Please **edit** your post with the file contents.  Look at your comment, is it readable?

Comment: As @πάνταῥεῖ mentioned, you can't use text methods (such as `getline`) to read general binary. Otherwise, the reading will erroneously attempt to read binary data as special ASCII sequences where they match. And a null (zero) value will be seen as an end-of-string when manipulating `line`.

Comment: Since the file is *binary*, you will need to know the data format or layout of the contents.  For example, is the data following `?>` an 8-bit byte?  16-bit value? a 32-bit value?  Is there padding?  Are the 16-bit and 32-bit values Big Endian or Little Endian?  The answers should be specified in the data format.  Or read the FORTRAN program that generated the file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [XML specification, especially section 2.6 Processing Instructions](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

> PIs are not part of the document's character data, but MUST be passed through to the application.

You must pass the data verbatim to the application.
If you want to view the data, you should print it in hex format, such as a hex dump utility does.

Also, in order to interpret the data, you must know the layout of the data.

Since it is application data, there is no guarantee that the data is printable.